# "data not defined" for vue jsx component

Tags: vue.js, import, export, vue-component, jsx

I'm new to vue and trying to export/import components and can't figure out why the below code doesn't work. I'm using webpack to bundle everything and as far as I know it is doing this successfully. The error that I get is coming from the browser's console:
1) [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: data is not defined"
2) ReferenceError: data is not defined at Proxy.render (menu.js:9)

I'm not sure what the errors mean because it appears to me that 'data' is defined.

The entire source code is here if interested: https://github.com/spencel/gwpp-v1-dev

**menu.js**

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            routes: [ '/database-viewer' ]
        }
    },
    render( h ) {
        return (
            <div class="Menu">{data.routes[0]}</div>
        )
    }
}
```

I tried this alternative code for **menu.js** as well:
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'

```
export default Vue.component( 'Menu', {
    data() {
        return {
            routes: [ '/database-viewer' ]
        }
    },
    render( h ) {
        return (
            <div class="Menu">{data.routes[0]}</div>
        )
    }
})
```

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
import Menu from './components/menu.js'

window.onload = function() {

    console.log( 'starting program' )

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#index',
        render: ( h ) => {
            return (
                <div>
                    <Menu/>
                </div>
            )
        }
    })

}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="index">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in JSX render function, you should use `this.routes[0]` rather than `data.routes[0]`